# where to check success or failure of an INSERT statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an **INSERT** statement with form data and I have to give back a message to the user if it was successful or not.

This is my code:

```
DB::get()->beginTransaction();
$this->inTransaction = true;

$queryInsert = "INSERT INTO DB::$buchungenTabelle 
                    (kurs_id, anrede, vorname, nachname, email, 
                     telefon, status, anzahl_teilnehmer) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ";

$stmt = DB::get()->prepare($queryInsert);

$stmt->execute(array($eventId, $salutation, $firstName, $familyName, 
                     $email, $telephone, 'gebucht', $participant));

DB::get()->commit();
$this->inTransaction = false;
```

Should I check the return value of `execute()` or of `commit()`? 
Is the return value of `execute()` reliable even if it is in a open transaction? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give a success message *unconditionally*. In case of a failed insert the reason is likely the server failure and in such a case a generalized error message "Server error. Please try later" should be shown by a dedicated error handler that is totally independent from your particular application code.

Besides, there is no need for a transaction at all. therefore your code would be

```
$queryInsert = "INSERT INTO DB::$buchungenTabelle 
                (kurs_id, anrede, vorname, nachname, email, 
                 telefon, status, anzahl_teilnehmer) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
DB::get()->prepare($queryInsert)->execute(array($eventId, $salutation, $firstName, 
           $familyName, $email, $telephone, 'gebucht', $participant));
echo "Success";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wanted to do a transaction because these events have a maximal number of participants and I wanted to add a validation of the data. Do you think is the transaction in this case superflous too?

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. What sort of validation you wanted to add?

Comment: I mean a validation of the posted data and to check if there are enough available places for this event (here I need another query)

Comment: In case you are afraid for the race condition, you need not a transaction but a table lock. You better ask another question regarding this one.